チャットワークの予約投稿ができるようなGASを開発したい
チャットワークの予約投稿ができるようなGASを開発したいです。
以下のコードにて作成しましたが、上手く反応せず、、、
スクリプトの保存・実行完了するのですが、実際にはチャットワークには投稿されていません。
投稿日時何時何分を過ぎると投稿し、1回投稿すると実行日が記録され、それ以降は投稿しない仕組みとしたいです。
以下スクリプトが誤っている点をご教示いただけますと幸いです。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

function myFunction() {
   
  // スプレットシート読み込み
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('シート１');//シート名を変更した場合は修正
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
   
  const token = "チャットワークのAPIを入力します";
   
  // ChatworkAPIクライント作成
  const client = ChatWorkClient.factory({token: token});
   
  // 実行日時
  const today = new Date();
   
  // スプレットシートに記載がある分だけ繰り返す
  for(var i = 3; i <= lastRow; i++) {
     
    const room_id = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue(); // ルームID
    const message = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); // 投稿内容
    const reservation_date = new Date(sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue()); // 投稿日
    const push_date = new Date();
     
    // E列が空白かつ、D列に記載されている日付が現時刻より前だった場合に送信
   if(sheet.getRange(i, 5).isBlank()&&reservation_date < push_date){
      client.sendMessage({
        room_id: room_id,
        body: message
      });
       
      // 実行日時の記録
      sheet.getRange(i, 5).setValue(push_date);
    }
  }
   
}


エラー発生の有無。エラーが発生している場合は、エラーメッセージ。また、ChatWorkClient ライブラリを使用していることを前提条件に記載すると、回答を得やすくなると思います。

for ループ内の処理は動作していますか？
質問に掲載された画像の例だと、2 行目にデータが入っています。この時、const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() で最終行を取得していますが、lastRow は、2 となります。
そうすると、以下の for ループは条件に合致しないためループ内の処理は実行されません。
for (var i = 3; i <= lastRow; i++) {

以下のように修正すれば、2 行目に値が入っている場合でも動作すると思います。
for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {

Google Apps Script であれば、Debug 実行で起動して、ステップ実行で処理がどのように進んでいるか、変数に何が入っているかが追跡できます。もしくは、console.log() を要所要所にいれ、想定通りに処理が進んでいるか、変数に何が入っているかをログ出力で確認すると良いと思います。

ありがとうございます！無事組み直して解決できました。丁寧にご回答頂き誠にありがとうございました。
